# is there native images to attach to buttons on ios storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I Want to show a Native axe button and Native V Button on my view in Swift (similar to this one) :

[image]

Is there some system clip arts on iOS (similar to Android) that you can use to show
Native system Information buttons or native alert images on Buttons ?

here is what i mean (equivalent) on android:

[image]

Comment: it's not a good approach to relay on system resources  as it would change

Comment: There are some really common icons that are not only used widely across iOS, but also other platforms and tons of their-party applications and even websites, some of which have been with us for years now. 1) Those are *not* likely to change and 2) even if they do for iOS, people will still understand what the old ones mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [Apple Design Resources](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/). It contains basic system element designs in popular formats (Sketch, PhotoShop, e.t.c)

There are also very few predefined UI element styles, but the set is very limited (e.g. see `UIButton` types)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are system icons. Built-in icons that represent common tasks and types of content in a variety of use cases.

Check Apple Human Interface Guidelines

[System Icons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/system-icons/)